# Problem to create a good SEO friendly route with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a SEO project with Laravel, I want to use the routes to config a friendlys dynamic urls.
This is my route:

```
# Designs
    Route::get('/d/{article}-{tag}-{design_name}-{design_id}',['as' => 'web.product_design', 'uses' => 'ProductController@getProductDesign']);
```

I want to build this SEO friendly url: **/d/mug-harry-potter-wingardium-leviosa-xfdsfsdf**

And that's what I call the route into any laravel blade view:

```
 route('web.product_design',['article' => 'mug'), 'tag' => str_slug('Harry Potter'), 'design_name' => str_slug('Wingardium Leviosa'), 'design_id' => 'xfdsfsdf'])
```

The problem is that inside the ProductController I don't receive these parameters as I would like. I think Laravel confuses when it starts and when it finishes the slugs.
For example, in the controller method...

```
# Product Design Page
    public function getProductDesign($article,$tag,$design_name,$design_id) {
      dd($article); // It gives me back 'mug', that's right.
      dd($tag); // It return me 'harry', is WRONG, I want to get 'harry-potter'.
      dd($design_name); // It return me 'potter', is WRONG, I want to get 'wingardium-leviosa'.
      dd($design_id); // It return me 'wingardium-leviosa-xfdsfsdf', is WRONG, I want to get 'xfdsfsdf'.
     }
```

**How can I build a url SEO friendly and at the same time be able to take the parameters correctly within the controller method?**

Comment: use `/` instead of `-`

Comment: No, I need to create it with '-'

Comment: if the parameter `article` has `-`, how laravel know.For example: 'harry-potter'

Comment: A nice explanition and tutorial here : https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable and here is well : https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-53-how-to-create-seo-friendly-sluggable-urlexample.html?utm_source=learninglaravel.net

Answer (score 1):

If you got this in your code

```
mug-harry-potter-wingardium-leviosa-xfdsfsdf
```

and exploded it on `-` then you would be in the same boat. How would you know that harry-potter was a single entity and not two.  If you want to have spaces in your parameters, and then slugify them, then you need to choose a different separator in the rest of the URL.

You could switch to `_` instead?

```
Route::get('/d/{article}_{tag}_{design_name}_{design_id}'
```

so your url is now

```
mug_harry-potter_wingardium_leviosa_xfdsfsdf
```